# When making an offer, can HR override a successful set of interviews with senior management?

Tags: recruitment, human-resources

I recently completed a months-long set of interviews for a senior management job with international responsibilities. It's a lot of work, but it's balanced by a hefty package.
I only interviewed with execs and VPs, everybody was very happy and things went very well.
Now HR reached out to prepare my offer letter. She is surprised about the amount of money and the seniority we discussed, and wants me to explain why I am worth that much money, so that she can make a case internally for the company to give me the money and the role... that were the whole reason for all these interviews to happen.

The question is: should I entertain this HR person's request, and justify my value from scratch? She doesn't know what specialist knowledge I bring or what I can do, but it's a barrier now. Is this something one is expected to do, is it a red flag and I should move on, or else?

(general application of this question: HR lowballing after all interviews went well)

Comment: Who exactly in HR? Head of? VP? If you discussed specific seniority/compensation with specific people you should point HR in their direction.

Comment: That should be the company's problem, not yours. I think you can only make yourself look worse.

Comment: It's some internal recruiter or HR person, not head of HR or anything like that.

Comment: *should I entertain this HR person's request* What alternative do you have? Walk away? Why would you not give them the information they're asking for?

Comment: Whoaa! What a *tremendous* recruiting tactic. After an executive-level candidate has an offer, call them and question them about whether they're worth it.  Do this especially for the candidates your company's trying hard to recruit.  It's just  bizarre.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes and no. As you mention HR lack the knowledge.

BUT it's the role of other itnernal people in company (execs and VPs) to inform the HR about negotiated titles and pay. They know the rules of their company. Not you.

Yes, HR is right explaining that they need to prepare case for it. Because it's probably outside the book. But again, it's not you who wrote to her about the amount of money. She should have asked person who send her that number.

And this is something you should ask her to do.

> Dear XXXX.
>   Seniority and pay were discussed during my interviews with XIX, XXYYX, ZZZ and BLBLBL. I'm not aware of which one reported to you our final agreement but please refer to them as they will be the best to explain.

Remember. It's the company that KNOW WHY they want to you to pay the amount. Not you.

Comment: this was very good, thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition to this, you should consider directly contacting the people you discussed your salary with, to inform them that HR disagrees. This allows them to tackle the problem from their end, too.